# Content security policy frame-ancestors not working in IE 11

Tags: asp.net, content-security-policy

The intent is to stop other sites from showing the content of our site in an iframe.

I can't use `X-Frame-Options = SAMEORIGIN` due to URL of the site. The main as www.xyz.com and the sub as sec.xyz.com.

So I resorted to Content Security Policy (... represents other domains etc)

```
<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' localhost ...; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;               style-src 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src * data; font-src * data:;               frame-ancestors 'self' localhost ...;" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

FF and Chrome do not display the site inside a test page iframe.

[image]

Now IE 11 shows the site inside the iframe since frame-ancestors is not supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

I have tried adding the header `X-Content-Security-Policy` in global file but IE 11 still shows the site.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self' localhost ...");
    }
```

[image]

How can I make IE 11 to adhere to header `X-Content-Security-Policy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support `frame-ancestors` for `X-Content-Security-Policy`. Targeting IE using `X-Frame-Options` and using `ALLOW-FROM`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: The ALLOW-FROM option is no longer available and has been deprecated.. you need to use CSP frame-ancestors if you want to specify other domains..
x-frame-options only supports DENY and SAMEORIGIN

[QUOTE]
ALLOW-FROM uri 
This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it. In supporting legacy browsers, a page can be displayed in a frame only on the specified origin uri. The Content-Security-Policy HTTP header has a frame-ancestors directive which you can use instead.
[/QUOTE]